# Getting RDS free disc space using Telegraf and Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, telegraf

Here's what I want: to get the current value of free disc space on RDS using Telegraf.

To that end I'm using Telegraf's Cloudwatch input (see configuration below). I am getting some metrics, but they all appear to have the SAME value. Max == Min, which (to me) sounds wrong. I am expecting Max to be the size of the RDS disc and Min to be the currently unused space. This is also supported by a test I carried with the AWS CLI.

So, am I doing something wrong? is this a bug in telegraf?

here's my telegraf config:

```
[[inputs.cloudwatch]]
region = "us-west-2"
period = '1m'
delay = '5m'
interval = '5m'
namespace = 'AWS/RDS'
[[inputs.cloudwatch.metrics]]
names = ['FreeStorageSpace']
[[inputs.cloudwatch.metrics.dimensions]]
  name = 'DBInstanceIdentifier'
  value = '*'
```

here's the output for one RDS instance - notice how the value '103560384512' repeats for max, min, average and sum:

```
> cloudwatch_aws_rds,db_instance_identifier=my-rds-instance,host=ip-172-31-47-37,node_name=my-rds-instance,region=us-west-2,unit=bytes free_storage_space_average=103560384512,free_storage_space_maximum=103560384512,free_storage_space_minimum=103560384512,free_storage_space_sample_count=1,free_storage_space_sum=103560384512 1547418720000000000
```

and here's AWS's CLI equivalent. I've tried Max, Min and I'm getting very different numbers, which makes sense. Below is the output for Min, on another disc:

```
aws cloudwatch   get-metric-statistics  --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name FreeStorageSpace   --region us-east-2 --start-time 2019-01-12T20:00:00Z --end-time 2019-01-12T23:59:00Z --period 3600 --statistics Minimum

"Datapoints": [
    {
        "Timestamp": "2019-01-12T21:00:00Z",
        "Minimum": 19796946944.0,
        "Unit": "Bytes"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2019-01-12T23:00:00Z",
        "Minimum": 19792580608.0,
        "Unit": "Bytes"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2019-01-12T22:00:00Z",
        "Minimum": 19794690048.0,
        "Unit": "Bytes"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2019-01-12T20:00:00Z",
        "Minimum": 19798822912.0,
        "Unit": "Bytes"
    }
],
"Label": "FreeStorageSpace"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out - there's nothing wrong here, but it's a little counter-intuitive. The FreeStorageSpace metric is a metric, and as such it can have a min, a max and an average - when sampled over time. If you sample it over a period of '1m' (as I did), then it's just a single datapoint and then, obviously, the max==min==average. In addition, the value it returns is in bytes, and to get it back to Mb you need to divide it by (1024^2)